# Magento 1.9.2 - Update custom attribute 'delivery_time' in the configurable product process

Tags: javascript, php, magento

I´m using Magento 1.9.2.4 (1.9.2.3 in my Testpage) and I have some configurable products with more than 1 option and each product (child products of the configurable one) has a different delivery time. I´ve created an attribute called "delivery_time" which I want to be updated when customer chooses an option. In order to achieve this I found some code snippets which i use. But it´s not updating correctly.

so here is my app/design/frontend/rwd/fitgmbh/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml

```
<?php
$_product = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes) && $_product->isConfigurable()):?>
<dl>
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
<dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
<dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
    <div class="input-box">
        <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select"
                onchange="return changeSku(<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>, this);">
            <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>
        </select>
    </div>
</dd>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
<script type="text/javascript">
var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<?php endif;?>
<?php
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$col = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
$productMap = array();
foreach($col as $simpleProduct){
$productMap[$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getDeliveryTime();
}
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
    echo $simple_product->getName() . " - " . $simple_product->getDeliveryTime() . "<br>";
}
endif;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
$("delivery").update("Bitte Optionen wählen");
});

function changeSku(confAttributeId, sel) {
var productMap = <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($productMap);?>;
var selectedAttributeId = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
if (selectedAttributeId) {
    var options = spConfig.config.attributes[confAttributeId].options;
    var productId = options.find(function (option) {return option.id == selectedAttributeId}).products[0]
    $("delivery").update("Lieferzeit: " + productMap[productId]);
} else {
    $("delivery").reset(); //just a test ;-)
}
}
</script>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after') ?>
```

and I show the output in app/design/frontend/rwd/fitgmbh/template/catalog/product/view.phtml with

```
<div id="delivery"></div>
```

I know that it might be hard to understand my problem, so I guess I have to provide a link to my [Testpage](http://www.shop.fitgmbh.eu/motorola-dm1400-4). In the configurable block I´ve listed all available option combinations, where the last number "stands for" my (test) delivery_time (1-12). I have really no idea what I have to do in order for this code to work properly. I think a part of the "easiest" solution might be to just reset all inputs if a customer "goes" back in the option-choosing-process. But my javascript-skills aren´t really existent. Apart from this some other delivery updates aren´t correct either. But after hours of trial and error I gave up, at least for the moment. Maybe someone of you can help me. I´m really thankfull for every hint! I hope that I have described my "problem" in an appropriated way.

I´ve created a module called "Arithon_DeliveryUpdate", as suggested by Chris Rogers,  but I´ve never created modules with an observer or a router. So there´s definitely something wrong with my module. At least its active ;-)

app/code/local/Arithon/DeliveryUpdate/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
<modules>
    <Arithon_DeliveryUpdate>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </Arithon_DeliveryUpdate>
</modules>
<frontend>
    <routers>
        <catalog>
            <args>
                <module>Arithon_DeliveryUpdate</module>
                <frontName>delivery_time</frontName>
            </args>
        </catalog>      
    </routers>  
</config>
```

app/code/local/Arithon/DeliveryUpdate/controllers/DeliveryController.php

```
<?php
public function updateAction() {
$match = 0;
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    extract($this->getRequest()->getPost());
    $_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
    $_attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attrId);
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    if ($_product && $_attribute && is_object($_product) && $_product->type_id == 'configurable') {
        $_attrCode = $_attribute->getData('attribute_code');
        $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
        foreach($childProducts as $child) {
            $cId = $child->getId();
            $v = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($cId, $_attrCode, $storeId);
            if ($v == $selectValue) {
                $configAttr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'delivery_time');
                $configAttrId = $configAttr->getId();
                $configAttrValue = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($cId, 'delivery_time', $storeId);
                $match = array("attrId" => $configAttrId, "attrValue" => $configAttrValue);
                break;
            }
        }                
    }
}
return $match;
}
?>
```

And my modified configurable.phtml

```
<?php
$_product    = $this->getProduct();
$_attributes = Mage::helper('core')->decorateArray($this->getAllowAttributes());
?>
<?php if ($_product->isSaleable() && count($_attributes) && $_product->isConfigurable()):?>
<dl>
<?php foreach($_attributes as $_attribute): ?>
<dt><label class="required"><em>*</em><?php echo $_attribute->getLabel() ?></label></dt>
<dd<?php if ($_attribute->decoratedIsLast){?> class="last"<?php }?>>
    <div class="input-box">
        <select name="super_attribute[<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select" onchange="productAddToCartForm.updateDelivery(this, <?php echo $_product->getId() ?>);" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $attrId ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $attrId ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select"
                onchange="return changeSku(<?php echo $_attribute->getAttributeId() ?>, this) ;">
            <option><?php echo $this->__('Choose an Option...') ?></option>

        </select>
    </div>
</dd>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</dl>
<script type="text/javascript">
var spConfig = new Product.Config(<?php echo $this->getJsonConfig() ?>);
</script>
<?php endif;?>
<?php
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$col = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
$productMap = array();
foreach($col as $simpleProduct){
$productMap[$simpleProduct->getId()] = $simpleProduct->getDeliveryTime();
}
//echo $simpleProduct->getDeliveryTime();
if($_product->getTypeId() == "configurable"):
$conf = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->setProduct($_product);
$simple_collection = $conf->getUsedProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->addFilterByRequiredOptions();
foreach($simple_collection as $simple_product){
    echo $simple_product->getName() . " - " . $simple_product->getDeliveryTime() . "<br>";
}
endif;
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
if (typeof productAddToCartForm != "undefined") {
productAddToCartForm.updateDelivery= function(select, product_id) {
    if (select != null && product_id != null && typeof select.selectedIndex != "undefined") {
        var keyword = 'attribute';
        var url = '/deliveryupdate/delivery/update'; // don´t know what to put here
        var val = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
        var attrId = select.getAttribute("id").replace(keyword, "");
        var formData = {
            selectValue: val,
            productId: product_id,
            attrId: attrId
        }; 

        // Make request to controller which will determine which value the configurable_attr_placeholder
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            success: function(data) {
                // PHP returns string readily convertable to JSON
                var response = JSON.parse(data);
                if (typeof response == 'object') {
                    // JSON key values are attrId and attrValue
                    var delivEl = document.getElementById(keyword + response.attrId);
                    if (typeof delivEl != "undefined" && configSel) {
                        delivEl = response.attrValue;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
};
}
</script>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('after') ?>
```

Aside from mistakes, is this module supposed to actively update my custom attribute "delivery_time" so that I can use

```
<?php echo $_product->getdelivery_time()?>
```

in my view.phtml? I wouldn´t have to use

```
<div id="delivery"></div>
```

anymore?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Magento 1.9 still makes use of prototype for handling the `onchange` of a select. You could extend this functionality like so:

In **app/design/frontend/YOUR_INTERFACE/YOUR_THEME/template/catalog/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml** - add an extra function in your `onchange`:

```
<select onchange="productAddToCartForm.updateDelivery(this, <?php echo $_product->getId() ?>);" name="super_attribute[<?php echo $attrId ?>]" id="attribute<?php echo $attrId ?>" class="required-entry super-attribute-select">
```

Then in JS, extend the prototype:

```
if (typeof productAddToCartForm != "undefined") {

    productAddToCartForm.updateDelivery= function(select, product_id) {
        if (select != null && product_id != null && typeof select.selectedIndex != "undefined") {
            var keyword = 'attribute';
            var url = '/YOUR_ROUTER/delivery/update';
            var val = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
            var attrId = select.getAttribute("id").replace(keyword, "");
            var formData = {
                selectValue: val,
                productId: product_id,
                attrId: attrId
            }; 

            // Make request to controller which will determine which value the configurable_attr_placeholder
            jQuery.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: formData,
                success: function(data) {
                    // PHP returns string readily convertable to JSON
                    var response = JSON.parse(data);
                    if (typeof response == 'object') {
                        // JSON key values are attrId and attrValue
                        var delivEl = document.getElementById(keyword + response.attrId);
                        if (typeof delivEl != "undefined" && configSel) {
                            delivEl = response.attrValue;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };
}
```

**Note:** I am also using jQuery here since that library is now also available in Magento 1.9 and I personally like their AJAX function.

Notice I am calling a controller method (`var url = '/YOUR_ROUTER/delivery/update';`) using AJAX - this method will return your delivery time.

In order for this method to work you are going to need to [create a custom module](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/03/basics-creating-magento-module/) and setup an event router

So in app/code/local/YOUR/MODULE/controllers/DeliveryController:

```
public function updateAction() {
    $match = 0;
    if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
        extract($this->getRequest()->getPost());
        $_storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();
        $_attribute = Mage::getModel('catalog/resource_eav_attribute')->load($attrId);
        $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        if ($_product && $_attribute && is_object($_product) && $_product->type_id == 'configurable') {
            $_attrCode = $_attribute->getData('attribute_code');
            $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getUsedProducts(null, $_product);
            foreach($childProducts as $child) {
                $cId = $child->getId();
                $v = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($cId, $_attrCode, $storeId);
                if ($v == $selectValue) {
                    $configAttr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'delivery_time');
                    $configAttrId = $configAttr->getId();
                    $configAttrValue = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product')->getAttributeRawValue($cId, 'delivery_time', $storeId);
                    $match = array("attrId" => $configAttrId, "attrValue" => $configAttrValue);
                    break;
                }
            }                
        }
    }
    return $match;
}
```

**Note** this will get the config product - get all used products and search their delivery times then return it. Ready to be used in the JS

This SHOULD get the correct delivery times. You can also use this controller to return any other info about your associated product to update other things! Please note, this is untested code so do ask if you're stuck!

Really hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will try this as soon as possible! I´ll give a responsonse wether it works or not or if I´m able/not able to apply your suggestion correctly. Thanks again!

Comment: I tried to use your suggestions but my module, as described above, isn´t working correctly. Maybe you could have a look on my exercises again?

Comment: Hey man, [have at look at this](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/magento-custom-module-development--cms-20643) it states some prerequisites - debugging modules can be hairy. This article can help.